# Создать библиотеку которая хранится в .txt найти книгу автора и отсортировать по названию

Tags: java, сортировка, поиск

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите искомого автора или книгу: ");
String searchWord = sc.nextLine();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("J:\\file.txt")); 
byte[] content = new byte[fis.available()];

fis.read(content);
fis.close();

String[] lines = new String(content, "Cp1251").split("\n"); 
int i = 1;
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    int j = 1;
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(searchWord)) {
            System.out.println("искомая книга " + searchWord + " "+ "найдено в " + i + "-й строке, " + j + "-е слово");
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Mой код спрашивает и выводит:

```
Введите искомого автора или книгу: 
Бальзак
искомая книга Бальзак найдено в 4-й строке, 3-е слово
искомая книга Бальзак найдено в 5-й строке, 3-е слово
```

Kак теперь взять всю строку с автором и названием книги и отсортировать книги по названию или вывести сообщение - книги нет?

Comment: Какая структура file.txt? Почему не читать построчно с BufferedReader?

Comment: Структура txt вообще прсотая пока может потом усложню сделаю красиво все пока мне надо просто понять как сделать чтоб заработала поэтмоу она такая:
А. Дюма  название "Три мушкетера"
Барри Берд название "Java 8 для чайников"
Берт Бейтс, Кэтти Сьерра название "Изучаем Java"
Бальзак "Шагренева кожа"
Бальзак "Гобсек"
Ричард Бренсон "Теряя невинность"

Comment: Это не структура, это содержимое. Пока вы не продумаете структуру данных, нет смысла не то что дальше делать, а даже начинать. Подумайте - какие поля, длина или переменной длины, сепаратор полей, наличие пробелов или неопреелённх полей, возможна ли строка заголовка, ну и т.д..

Comment: Спасибо за совет! буду писать)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, выводится должны строки примерно такие: "искомая книга "НАЗВАНИЕ КНИГИ" найдено в 4-й строке, 3-е слово"?? 
Чтобы код сильно не менять, предлагаю создать коллекцию, в которую добавлять lines[i] (сразу после вывода на консоль строки), т.е. сюда

```
if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(searchWord)) {
            System.out.println("искомая книга " + searchWord + " "+ "найдено в " + i + "-й строке, " + j + "-е слово");
    }
```

Проверку на наличие книги всунуть сразу после этого:

```
else System.out.println("искомая книга");
```

Так вы создадите коллекцию строк в которой будут книги нужного автора.
Потом в зависимости от структуры начального файла txt нужно из строк выбрать название книг и добавить в еще одну коллекцию. Коллекцию лучше сразу выбрать TreeSet, чтобы не нужно было сортировать (она хранит значения в алфавитном порядке).

Comment: я пытался, походу коллекции знаю очень плохо, не приводятся типы, lines Типа String и в коллекцию не хочет заходить(
так вы имели ввиду или я туплю, вот код изначальный:
//почему-то не поучается вставить этот кусок как код не 4 пробела не <pre><code> ни ctrl + K не попомагет( прошу прощения
for (String word : words) {
if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(searchWord)) {
System.out.println("искомая книга " + searchWord + " " + "найдено в " + i + "-й строке, " + j+ "-е слово");
//вот сюда добавить 
TreeSet<String>  al = new TreeSet<>();
     al =  lines;